# Magento CE won't let me use PayPal Standard without Express (which requires API credentials)

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-ce

The only options showing up in my admin are these:

Payments Advanced (Includes Express Checkout)
Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout)
Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout)

I see screenshots from other admins where the (Includes Express Checkout) does not appear after Payments Standard.  I'm using v1.9.1.0 which is currently the latest version of Magento CE.

The issue is that if I select "Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout)" I'm required to put in API credentials which I don't have (I don't want to upgrade my PayPal account, I just want the most basic payment option).

So, I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the Express Checkout option, or at the very least find a way to use only Payments Standard.

Any help would be appreciated.  I can't find any other people in the forums having this issue so I'm wondering if it's new to v1.9.1.0 or something.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: We have the same issue. Somehow the original payment method "Website Payments Standard" has got replaced by "Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout)" and I don't know how to revert it back. Neither I don't want to enter the API values. The scary thing is that we don't know how it happened on the production site.

Comment: For me, the problem was that under System>Configuration>General>General>Countries Option, I had countries other than UK selected. Once I removed them the Paypal Standard option appeared.

Answer (score 12):

I found the "steps to reproduce" and hotfix. Originally we enabled the "Website Payments Standard" payment method and then disabled because we had the problem with "Suspect Fraud" status. Immediately after I disabled the "Website Payments Standard" it turned into "Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout)" and I was not able to revert it back. This behaviour is always reproducible on Magento CE 1.9.1.0

I found out that if I enable the payment method directly in database, it reverts back to the "Website Payments Standard".

This is the query to re-enable it:

```
update core_config_data 
set value = '1' 
where path = 'payment/paypal_standard/active';
```

I am not sure why it behaves like that and we have not enable it on production yet because we are still trying to solve the "Suspect Fraud" status problem. We discovered that some of the modules we installed are causing conflicting (Stored Credits, Payment Charge etc) and thus charging incorrect amounts, but that is different story.

Comment: oh god thanks a lot! this shocked me for a while..

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. In my case, the `path` you mentioned was missing from `core_config_data` table. I had to insert it: **INSERT INTO  `core_config_data` (`config_id` ,`scope` ,`scope_id` ,`path` ,`value`) VALUES (NULL ,  'default',  '0',  'payment/paypal_standard/active',  '1'
);**

Comment: @MukeshChapagain there is no other dependencies based on this table? No other dependency record to be inserted in any other table? have you tested this?

Comment: I also had "Suspect Fraud" problem. I tried to use real address in order and it solved the problem.

Comment: @version.beta I managed to get Paypal standard back using the above query. The paypal standard is working fine until now. I haven't found other dependency yet.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Standard is an overused product name. From the merchant perspective it does not matter Standard or Express API used - in both cases fee are the same (the only thing different is an API calls) customer is redirected to the PayPal and pay for the goods or services. However there are an important differences between those in terms of user experience where EC is a winner, see https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_additional-payment-ref-impl1

To summarize **PayPal Express Checkout does not need an account upgrade and offers same Merchant fees, however works much better.** See PayPal Fees https://www.paypal-marketing.com/emarketing/partner/na/program/comparison_chart.html