# Magento Paypal integration stuck

Tags: checkout, paypal, magento-1.6, paypal-express, paypal-standard

Since a couple month i am having a problem with Paypal integration. Specifically "Paypal Express"

The problem is that some customers are stuck at the redirection, it's not continuing to Paypal.

- Sometimes it's not continuing after Paypal back to the shop to complete the order. In the back end I have some missing order numbers.
- When I try with my computer to pay with Paypal it works...
- The second problem is that "Paypal Standard" is not shown at checkout, that's why I had to choose "Paypal Express".

Error:

```
'PayPal NVP gateway errors: This transaction couldn't be completed. Please redirect your customer to PayPal (#10486: This transaction couldn't be completed). Correlation ID: 15378a2c52092. Version: 72.0.'
```

I'm working with Magento ver. 1.6

Answer (score 1):

I saw on Google that more people have the same issue and not only Magento webshops, also ZenCart en Shopify. Also, it doesn't seem to happen only for PayPal Express, but also PayPal Standard.

The issue is related to the customers card and/or PayPal account. I saw some comments on the Shopify forums where they mentioned that the issue was solved for some cases where the customer created an account on PayPal and added his/her credit card to that account. Problem is, there is no real solution for this, except that it's not a Magento error, but a PayPal error.

About the PayPal Standard not being visible in the cart for you, I tried it out with my Magento installation (v1.9.3.1) and all I can tell is that you need to be completely sure that the settings in the configuration for your store are correct. If that's not the case [this resolution on StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48810/magento-ce-wont-let-me-use-paypal-standard-without-express-which-requires-api) might help you out. If not, please specify your question and let us know what you've done to debug.