# Website Payments Standard won't allow Order Review (5th Step)

Tags: checkout

We are using Magento 1.9.1.1

We are setting up Website Payments Standard, and we want people to review their orders before going out to the PayPal website.

However, on Step 4 in the Checkout, when people select PayPal as a payment method, and click Continue to Step 5 (Order review), they are taken off to PayPal, without being able to carefully review their orders in Magento.

This is kind of frustrating, and we don't seem to find a way to fix it.

We tried to select "Skip Order Review Step" to "No", but it looks like that is an inner PayPal step, nothing to do with the classic 5th step in Magento's Checkout process.

Do you know how we can get that Step back?

It works when selecting other payment methods like Credit Card (saved) and Check/Money Order.

Thanks,

**EDIT**

On this video, strangely enough, they have it working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNukAPvmiQE

It seems like their Magento version doesn't merge Website Payments Standard with Express Checkout, like you have in the lattest 1.9.1.1.

Could this be the culprit?

We have disabled Express Checkout on the product and the Cart though, and it does not makes a difference.

Comment: This is the kind of link that PayPal generates when clicking on the Continue button on step 4: www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5JF78386D7324933A#/checkout/login This is Express Checkout kind of link, so it seems is interferring / taking priority over the Website Payments Standard way. I can't find how to disable it though, as it is "included" within WPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button shows that you are using Paypal Express. Disabling this method on the product and cart pages is merely a layout setting.

For Paypal Express, the behaviour is correct: after chosing the payment, you will be redirected to paypal. Then, after you confirm the purchase on their site, you will be redirected to the store where you have the review page as the very last step.

Afaik, Paypal Payments Standard is going to be deprecated and Paypal urges its customers to use Paypal Express instead.

If you search the web, you will also find that there are numerous issues with Magento 1.9.1.1 and Paypal Standard. In 1.9.0.1 it was even missing in the backend.

Maybe this answer can show you a way to fix it: [Magento CE won't let me use PayPal Standard without Express (which requires API credentials)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48810/magento-ce-wont-let-me-use-paypal-standard-without-express-which-requires-api)