# Difference b/w 1.9.0.1 vs 1.9.2.0 with related to Paypal

Tags: paypal, ce-1.9.2.0

we configured paypal for 1.9.0.1 version with merchant country India.

we can see "**Paypal website payments standard**" option

[image]

but in 1.9.2.0 version, we have "**Paypal website payments standard (include express checkout )**"

[image]

In 1.9.0.1 its going for "order review step" but in 1.9.2.0 its skipping order review step. I dont want to skip `order review step` in 1.9.2.0 also.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cancel the order from Paypal page without completing the payment, it will redirect you back to your cart page. The order will not get placed.

If you close the page after paypal redirection, without completing the payment(note that you do not have to press cancel here) the order will get placed with pending payment status

**Depending on the PayPal method you are using this can be treated differently.**

> PayPal Express, cancel operation is triggered in this controller:
>
> ```
> \app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Controller\Express\Abstract.php
> ```

```
public function cancelAction()
{
    try {
        $this->_initToken(false);
        // TODO verify if this logic of order cancelation is deprecated
        // if there is an order - cancel it
        $orderId = $this->_getCheckoutSession()->getLastOrderId();
        $order = ($orderId) ? Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId) : false;
        if ($order && $order->getId() && $order->getQuoteId() == $this->_getCheckoutSession()->getQuoteId()) {
            $order->cancel()->save();
            $this->_getCheckoutSession()
                ->unsLastQuoteId()
                ->unsLastSuccessQuoteId()
                ->unsLastOrderId()
                ->unsLastRealOrderId()
                ->addSuccess($this->__('Express Checkout and Order have been canceled.'))
            ;
        } else {
            $this->_getCheckoutSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Express Checkout has been canceled.'));
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_getCheckoutSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getCheckoutSession()->addError($this->__('Unable to cancel Express Checkout.'));
        Mage::logException($e);
    }

    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

Where it unset everything in the same place so you need to keep the quote.Check what you are getting here and code for you requirement. Note please override the core functionality. Do not change it directly.

Comment: I did't understood this : "Where it unset everything in the same place so you need to keep the quote." please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Can you switch to use the "Paypal Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout)".

[image]

Use the Advanced Settings in the "Credit Card Settings" section to disable the on-site credit card portion of processor.

[image]

Leave the Express checkout enabled. In the Advanced Settings of the "Express Checkout" section change "Display on Shopping Cart" to no.

This will force the user to go through checkout process, selecting PayPal as the payment processor in the 2nd to last step. On final submission the order is created, then the user is redirected to PayPal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But my requirement is different. I wanted to create an order in backend if customer did't paid the money through paypal.

Comment: if we select merchant country as `india` , it not showing `Paypal Payment Express Pro checkout` , but it showing `Paypal website payments standard (include express checkout )` when i configured this, than also its redirect to paypal site when we select "paypal as payment method.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by some research : [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48810/magento-ce-wont-let-me-use-paypal-standard-without-express-which-requires-api)

credits :  @Mukesh Chapagain

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (config_id ,scope ,scope_id ,path ,value) VALUES (NULL , 'default', '0', 'payment/paypal_standard/active', '1' );
```

once i run the query **express checkout** removed and order created in backend for failed transactions.

Comment: Oh! that was issue ?

Comment: similar solution is suggested by @David

Comment: No , he suggested express checkout. but when i used express checkout it was redirecting from payment method. but i needed normal payment method. however thanks a lot for both of you.